# How to instantiate IOSDriver to access its methods in the current session

Tags: java, appium, appium-ios, qaf

I am currently using the command in Qmetry Automation Framework

```
QAFExtendedWebdriver mydriver = getQAFDriver();
```

It will stores current driver in ´mydriver´ object so I can access its available methods.

Now I need to create a new driver object in the same current session itself to access IOSDriver specific methods.

```
IOSDriver<WebElement> driver= new IOSDriver<WebElement>(url, capabilities);
```

How to get current session `url`, `capabilities` to pass as parameters in
the above instantiation.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have provided `driverClass` [capability](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/qaf-2.1.7b/setting_driver_capabilities.html) having value fully qualified name of driver class. For example

**properties**:

```
driver.name=appiumDriver
appium.capabilities.driverClass=io.appium.java_client.ios.IOSDriver
```

You can get driver class object anytime  by casting underlying driver as below:

```
IOSDriver<WebElement> iosdriver = (IOSDriver)driver.getUnderlayingDriver();
```

**NOTE**: `driverClass` capability will not applicable with remote driver, so if you provide driver name `appiumRemoteDriver` then driver class will not be considered and you will get class cast exception in above statement.